# how to solve the libgnutls.so.28 issue?

Tags: linux

```
yum install autoconf automake gcc 
libtasn1-devel zlib zlib-devel trousers 
trousers-devel gmp-devel gmp xz texinfo 
libnl-devel libnl tcp_wrappers-libs 
tcp_wrappers-devel tcp_wrappers dbus 
dbus-devel ncurses-devel pam-devel 
readline-devel bison bison-devel flex 
gcc automake autoconf wget
```

Install Nettle:

```
wget http://www.lysator.liu.se/~nisse/archive/nettle-2.7.tar.gz
tar xvf nettle-2.7.tar.gz
cd nettle-2.7

./configure --prefix=/opt/

make && make install

cd ..
```

Install the latest GnuTLS, this version comes with a fix of security flaw:

```
wget ftp://ftp.gnutls.org/gcrypt/gnutls/v3.2/gnutls-3.2.12.tar.xz
tar xvf gnutls-3.2.12.tar.xz
cd gnutls-3.2.12
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/lib/:/opt/lib64/
NETTLE_CFLAGS="-I/opt/include/" NETTLE_LIBS="-L/opt/lib64/ -lnettle" HOGWEED_CFLAGS="-I/opt/include" HOGWEED_LIBS="-L/opt/lib64/ -lhogweed" 

./configure --prefix=/opt/

make && make install

cd ..
```

Install the Latest LibNL:

```
wget http://www.carisma.slowglass.com/~tgr/libnl/files/libnl-3.2.24.tar.gz
tar xvf libnl-3.2.24.tar.gz
cd libnl-3.2.24

./configure --prefix=/opt/

make && make install

cd ..
```

Install Ocserv

The latest version of ocserv is 0.8.0[1], if you want a git version, you might need to compile a recent version of automake and autoconf.

```
wget ftp://ftp.infradead.org/pub/ocserv/ocserv-0.8.0.tar.xz
tar xvf ocserv-0.8.0.tar.xz
cd ocserv-0.8.0
export LIBGNUTLS_CFLAGS="-I/opt/include/" LIBGNUTLS_LIBS="-L/opt/lib/ -lgnutls" LIBNL3_CFLAGS="-I/opt/include" LIBNL3_LIBS="-L/opt/lib/ -lnl-3 -lnl-route-3" 

./configure --prefix=/opt/

make && make install
```

When I run `certtool --generate-privkey --outfile ca-key.pem` , I encounter the following error:

```
[root@arx ~]# certtool --generate-privkey --outfile ca-key.pem

certtool: relocation error: certtool: symbol gnutls_srp_3072_group_prime, version GNUTLS_3_0_0 not defined in file libgnutls.so.28 with link time reference

[root@arx ~]#
```

How to fix the error?

Thanks.

PS: the os in my linux vps is centos 7. In centos 6, I didn't encounter the error above.

Comment: please use markdown to format your code blocks to clearly show what is going on - use backticks or indented blocks to show code/input/output